# "Stack overflow" error. Probably pointer out of list

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

First of all I am not proficient programing, so please be lenient. :)
I was curious what causes the error called "Stack overflow". I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

```
struct elem
{
    BITMAP * colltile;
    elem * next;
};
```

/* put some code here */

```
int collision_map (unsigned int poz_x, unsigned int poz_y)
{
    elem * wsk = this->where_the_head_of_list_is;
    int x,y;
    x = poz_x%64; //coord x on tile (0-63px)
    y = poz_y%64; //coord y on tile (0-63px)
    poz_x /= 64;  //preparing poz_x and poz_y to point on a tile on a grid
    poz_y /= 64;  //integers do not have to be floored

    //for (int j=(poz_y*(this->size_x)+poz_x); j>0; j--) //normally works... but
    for (int j=0; j<1000; j++) //this version is not
    {
        if ((!(wsk = wsk->next)) ||
            ((poz_x+1) > this->size_x) ||
            ((poz_y+1) > this->size_y))
        {   //should check if there is no new pointer or just out of map
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return getpixel(wsk->colltile, x, y); 
}
```

Why is the condition not working when `j` reaches the value of length of the list?

Comment: This code only causes stack overflow is `getpixel` calls `collision_map` again.

Comment: you googled for the answer and found this site...

Comment: wsk is of type elem and elem doesn't have a member called colltile, only callmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you can/have to do:

- Adding debug output will help you find the error. Add some `std::cerr << wsk << std::endl` in your code and check if/when it becomes zero.
- Possibly the pointer is zero at the beginning of your function at `elem* wsk= ...`. If this is the case `wsk->next` will access a null pointer. You have to check if the pointer is valid.
- Since you have pointer members in your class (as indicated by `this->where_the_head_of_list_is`) you need to implement copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor, which you might not have done. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) for an explanation.

Comment: - From the debug I found out that the next pointers are being selected in infinite loop, so here lays the problem.
- elem * wsk points on the right value
- for my class I've made constructor, destructor, but I have not created a copy constructor so far. I'll focus on that.

Comment: Crap... it turned out completly other function was endlessly calling itself (I estimated momentum wrongly and the character stuck in block checking if is he still in it - calling presented function). Anyway thank you for help :)